# How has physics been used to study mathematics?

Tags: experimental-physics

Suppose, I have the differential equation $ \frac{d^2\vec{ r(t)}}{dt^2} = \frac{\kappa}{|r|^2} \hat{r}$ and I wanted to know what kind of vector would solve the above equation give some initial conditions.. then instead of trying to solve the mathematics equation, I can simply make that scenario happen in real life and see how the solution to the equation should be. For example, when I'm near to surface of earth, it is very obvious that $ \vec{r(t)}$ must be a straight line because objects fall vertically downwards. (*)

Has there been similar ideas on using physics to understand solve abstract mathematics problems?

---

*: The written equation is just the differential equation governing how a mass moves under the influence of a gravitational field!

Comment: Apart from philosophical issues that one may hold that pure mathematics does not make statements about reality and hence experiments cannot have any bearing on it, your idea does not work in a case where you really don't know how to solve the equation - in order to know that the differential equation given models the actual physical situation, you must have been able to solve it independently of experiment and then have compared this computation to your observations.

Comment: This is a fun question, but i think it may be better suited for philosophy.stackexchange.com.. In short, i would argue categorically you can do no such thing. There's no a priori reason why mathematics applies to the physical world.

Comment: IF we can just accept that mathematics models the real world, and also that newton's mathematical laws are the one's which govern observation, then the observation can be used to know solve the mathematical problem

Comment: @Buraian there is no reason to accept that. Saying that newtons laws are those that govern observation is circular because how do you know they govern the motion of massive bodies if you cant solve them?

Comment: There are some instances where physicists have used sloppy math, then saw the result agrees with observations in some cases, and concluded the math had to work, so it can be applied it elsewhere.  The examples that come to mind are renormalization in QFT and the Dirac delta function.  In each case mathematicians rigorously proved how the math worked after physicists started using it.

Comment: Hmm the I don't think we have tested newton's equations for every single physical situation yet ( for example pendulum, we only have approximation for small angles) . We put some blind faith that it should work @InertialObserver (since it hasn't gone wrong before)

Comment: @Buraian that's simply just not true that we can only solve it using small angle approximation. just because it's non an analytical solution doesn't mean it's not a solution

Comment: @Buraian You might be interested in *The Mathematical Mechanic: Using Physical Reasoning to Solve Problems* by Mark Levi.

Comment: I didn't say that it is 'not' a solution, I simply said that we are only bothering with solving newton's laws because we trust that they should give us the 'right' answer

Comment: Re, "...simply make that scenario happen..." [Analog computers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_computer) used to be a thing: You could "solve" a differential equation with an analog computer by setting up an electronic circuit that is modeled by the equation, dialing in the initial conditions (voltages), and then let'r rip.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Ok but that's just an equation represented by electronic components is a specific configuration (circuit). It's not a physical experiment as the OP envisages it.

Comment: @Gert, I don't understand. How is constructing an electronic circuit and observing its behavior _not_ a phyical experiment? Are electronic circuits unphysical?

Comment: I guess in a way it count? You've modelled mathematics using electronics, in the same question I had said to use physics to model mathematics. I honestly did not expect such an application :P

Comment: @SolomonSlow I wrote: *It's not a physical experiment* **as the OP envisages it**.What the OP believes (his question) isn't possible, no matter how many analog circuits you throw at it. I think you're not understanding the OP's question.

Comment: *I honestly did not expect such an application* It still isn't remotely the same. In the Analog Computer thing you simply use an analog computer to solve a known DE. A far cry from your claim...

Comment: @Gert, my claim was that you can study the behavior of a differential equation by constructing an electronic circuit that is expected to obey that equation, and then you turn it on and watch what it does. A so-called "analog computer" is a kit of components (especially, precision op-amps) and instruments that make it easy to construct and observe such a circuit.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I fully understand that. I studied Operational Amplifiers at Uni. But analog computers, interesting as they are, are not what the OP has in mind. E.g. a rolling ball with friction on a variable incline is not an AC and will not generate or solve the required Newtonian EoM for you.

Comment: An AC is no more than a computer solving whatever equation it is designed to solve.

Comment: @Gert, You're saying that what we _call_ a thing that obeys a certain law determines whether or not we are allowed to say that the thing _embodies_ the law? E.g., a swinging pendulum is a physical embodiment of a simple harmonic oscillator, but an analog computer that is configured to do the same thing... That's not a physical embodiment, it's _just_ a computer? What if I build the identical circuit into an analog, electronic music synthesizer? Does it become a physical oscillator because I didn't call it a computer? or is the real problem that it's "electronic" instead of "physical?"

Comment: @SolomonSlow I'm saying that *E.g. a rolling ball with friction on a variable incline is not an AC and will not generate or solve the required Newtonian EoM for you.*. Not complicated to my mind. A computer made of sand would still only be a computer, no matter how well it was programmed to  solve some equation or other. I'm off now. Good luck.

Comment: What the OP wants is simply not how physics works. We observe, draw some inferences, propose some hypotheses, suggest a model, then test the model against controlled experiments and/or observed data.